# Super type/ Sub type db implementation

Tags: database, ms-access

I am working on DB where I am struggling to enforce sub-type discriminator.

```
(Super type) Employee Table: **Emp_ID**, F_Name,L_Name,Sex, Dept_Type {"H","S","N"}
(Sub-type) Hardware Table: **Emp_ID**, Level,Manager....
(Sub-type) Software Table: **Emp_ID**, Experience,Skill....
(Sub-type) Network Table: **Emp_ID**, Certification,Proficiency....
```

I need to know how can i enforce on DB MS-Access level that EMP ID with Dept_Type "H" only could insert record in hardware table not in software or network table. Similarly EMP_ID with Dept_Type "S" can only insert record in Software table not in the other two tables.

Is there a way to enforce on DB level using MS Access ? Or it can be only enforce through application

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that: a) employees listed in the Hardware table must be ones listed in the Employee table with Dept_Type H, and, b) employees listed in the Software table must be ones listed in the Employee table with Dept_Type S, you might try something like this:

1. Add a Dept_Type field to each of the Hardware and Software tables.
2. In the Dept_Type field in the Hardware table, set the Required property to Yes and the Validation Rule property to "H".
3. In the Dept_Type field  in the Software table, set the Required property to Yes and the Validation Rule property to "S".
4. In the Employee table, create a unique index on the combination of the Emp_ID and Dept_Type fields.
5. Add a relationship that enforces referential integrity between the Employee table (on the "one" side) and the Hardware table (on the "many side") on the combination of the Emp_ID and Dept_Type fields.
6. Add a relationship that enforces referential integrity between the Employee table (on the "one" side) and the Software table (on the "many side") on the combination of the Emp_ID and Dept_Type fields.